# Pdf file in webview not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webview

when user clicks on button in alertviewController, then I have opened a viewcontroller using present modally segue, This opened viewcontroller has webview which loads pdf file.This pdf file is stored within app and i am using webview to load request for this.But when pdf file is opened in webview , webview is not scrolling

Below is code to load pdf file in webview

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Tutorial - Guided Access and Guided Access passcodes", ofType: "pdf")
        GANoticeWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)))
        GANoticeWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
        GANoticeWebView.scrollView.bounces = true;
        self.view .addSubview(GANoticeWebView)
```

This pdf file has 2 pages. But user can see only first half of page as webview is not scrolling.

Please help me in this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is the frame of `GANoticeWebView` correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checked for UserInteraction on WebView and Scrolling enabled on scrollView of WebView.

In one of my project I am doing the same thing and apart from your code. I am adding these two lines.

Comment: Thanks. How can i miss this?

Comment: @Nitya do let me know if it works for you. I just rechecked working fine at my end.